# Programmatically change a Frame position

Tags: xcode, landscape-portrait, programmatically-created

I've created programmatically a View, an UIImageView and a Button. The problem is that i need to update their position if the device switches from Portrait to Landscape, how can I do it?

This should be the code that checks if the Device is in Portrait or Landscape mode

```
- (void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
    if (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)
    {


    }
    else
    {


    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
- (void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
if (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)
    {
//change the frame for sideways direction
btn.frame=CGRectMake(x,y,width,height);
imgView.frame=CGRectMake(x,y,width,height);
view.frame=CGRectMake(x,y,width,height);
    }
else
    {
//change the frame for up/down
btn.frame=CGRectMake(x,y,width,height);
imgView.frame=CGRectMake(x,y,width,height);
view.frame=CGRectMake(x,y,width,height);
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the code along the lines of `[self setFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, width, height)];`
In this case `self` will be the name of your `UIImageView, View or Button`

Answer (score 0):

Usually you should use AutoLayout for this case.
You can read about it here: http://www.raywenderlich.com/50317/beginning-auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-7-part-1

If you want something special, you can use

```
- (void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
```

or

```
- (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation
```

Comment: I know I should use autolayout but the I had to create 3 elements programmatically and I couldn't create them in the Interface Builder, anyways thanks :)

Comment: @user3789527 You can add constraits in code :)

    NSLayoutConstraint *myConstraint =[NSLayoutConstraint 
                  constraintWithItem:mybutton
                  attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                  relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                  toItem:mylabel
                  attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                  multiplier:5
                  constant:0];

    [superview addConstraint: myConstraint];

Comment: damn thought I couldn't add constraints programmatically! Thanks a lot, this will save me lot of coding :P

Answer (score 0):

you do it in viewWillLayoutSubviews.
Normally, you don't need to be of any orientation if all you need to do is to have frame change with respect to bounds of superview.